# Replace blanks with a string with DAX coding in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data in Excel and I have uploaded in power bi, created a visualisation using a chart which looks like -

blank, CP, Jj10 are basically my y axis and dashes are my bars of horizontal chart. I have tried to show how my chart looks like because I don't get any other option

(Blank)**-------------**998

CP**-----------**56

Jj10--------44

0BN**--------------**77

Hi-po**---**2

Naas**-------**21

There is a column named **performance** (sheet_name=Empl_data) and what I want is to replace the blanks with **Non-GT** in power bi with creating a new column.

**What my output should look like -**

(Non-GT)**-------------**998

CP**-----------**56

Jj10--------44

0BN**--------------**77

Hi-po**---**2

Naas**-------**21

I have tried this -

Non-GT = IF(ISBLANK('Empl_data'[performance]),"Non-GT",'Empl_data'[performance])

What i get is

Non-GT**----------------964**

(Blank)**-------------**34

CP**-----------**56

Jj10--------44

0BN**--------------**77

Hi-po**---**2

Naas**-------**21

I just want to replace blanks with Non-TSG completely but still it shows blank. Please help me out to solve the problem and please let me know if I have made clear what my prblm is.

My data -

| Empl_id | Empl_name | performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99807 | Somman paul |  |
| 0076 | Richards.M |  |
| 8870 | Maheen Josef.T |  |
| 11209 | Dojar Farah |  |
| 6651 | Macklegn Sagoe | Hi-po |
| 551 | Cada Farez | Jj10 |
| 12 | Qwezy Goha | Hi-po |
| 6567 | Beheriop Produse | CP |
| 2227 | John semmers | 0BN |
| 656 | Majeeio .f |  |
| 80100 | Drejju Yan |  |

Comment: Show sample data from your excel and the final output you need in Power BI from those sample data.

Comment: I have added my sample data by editing the qstn and what my output looks like I have made it bolder. Now is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Is it actually Blank where it is showing nothing? First confirm there are spaces or really null in the data, then apply conditions as bellow-

```
Non-GT = 
IF(
    'Empl_data'[performance] = BLANK() || 'Empl_data'[performance] = "",
    "Non-GT",
    'Empl_data'[performance]
)
```

**Q:** Where you are transforming data with that condition? Power Query Editor? Or creating Measure or Calculated column?

Comment: I have created a new column and then tried the code which I have shown

Comment: sir I have tried your code but it still showing same result as what it shows previously with my code. And I have checked they are completely blank  cells. Sir let me tell you I have uploaded two files one is Empl_data and other is Rating_data and then I have join them in power bi itself. In the axis I have taken - **performance** (from Empl_data) and in values - **code** (from Rating_data) . Is it comes due to the join? Or might be something else

Comment: Can you provide the sample report file (.pbix) with sample data?

Comment: Sir I would love to share...that's not a issue, but I think in SO it's not safe to share as it is  public community. is there any way to share you personally?. I have sent a request in linked in but you didn't Accepted it :(

Comment: You can upload the file in google drive and share the public link here.

Comment: Sir I have shared my drive link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228613/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-red-vibes).